# I sending message to a browser, but the browser receive only part of it

Tags: java, utf-8

I wrote a simple server in Java, but I have a problem. The code responsible for sending responses to browsers looks like this:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(this._client.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8), true);

out.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n");
out.write("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\n");
out.write("Access-Control-Allow-Headers *\n");
out.write("Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8\n");
out.write("Accept-Encoding: UTF-8\n");
out.write("Content-Length: " + message.length() + "\n");
out.write("\n");
out.write(message);
out.flush();
```

The *message* variable contains a JSON string. When I want to return a simple string contains only ASCII chars it's ok - a browser gets everything:

```
{"data":[{"name":"{\"nick\":\"abc\",\"message\":\"czesc\"}","event":"message"}],"id":"cb822555313d73a697e5f908b1f21fff5eb85fedf062f301a4932d9547c1d266"}
```

But when *message* has polish chars, for example:

```
{"data":[{"name":"{\"nick\":\"abc\",\"message\":\"cześć\"}","event":"message"}],"id":"cb822555313d73a697e5f908b1f21fff5eb85fedf062f301a4932d9547c1d266"}
```

the browser receive only this:

```
{"data":[{"name":"{\"nick\":\"abc\",\"message\":\"cześć\"}","event":"message"}],"id":"cb822555313d73a697e5f908b1f21fff5eb85fedf062f301a4932d9547c1d266
```

As you see it is the same string, but without last two chars.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, the "length" has to include the *multiple characters required for Unicode conversion*. Your UTF8 characters are taking more than a single character up. You will need to calculate the *real* message length, not just the length of the string which in Java is always UTF16.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytesOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(bytesOut, "UTF8");


out.write(yourString);
out.flush();
byte[] tstBytes = bytesOut.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Ok, but how can I do it?